# Paypal: empty cart session soon after the form submit button is clicked

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart, paypal

How can I delete the cart session soon after the submit button is clicked to send the form data to paypal?

For instance,

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Book 1" />

...

<button type="submit" name="submit">Check Out</button>

</form>
```

And I need to run this script to empty the cart,

```
unset($_SESSION[SESSION_CART]);
unset($cart);
```

It seems that it only can be done in javascript's ajax? What about just http or php?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd empty the cart upon re-directing to your site after the transaction was completed - that way if it gets aborted (eg. the user wants to delete/add something) they can do with less fuss!

However, if you want to delete everything - then you need to POST the form to a page on your website, and then re-POST the data to PayPal

Comment: Thanks - 'empty the cart upon re-directing' I thought of that. but it requires the buyer to click the return button from paypal after payment. If they close the browser immediately without returning to my site, then the cart will never be emptied.

Comment: If they never return and the session expires, then it won't be much of a problem - but I should think you can still get a transaction reference somehow via the API and clear it that way (assuming there is an identifiable piece of info that you can grab)

Comment: 'If they never return and the session expires' it seems most browsers will set the session to expire automatically after a certain time, especially Chrome.

Comment: `but I should think you can still get a transaction reference somehow via the API and clear it that way` yes there is a `transaction reference` from paypal ipn but ipn is server to server, not server to browser. Thanks :-)